# GZip HttpResponse using XSL Transformer

Tags: java, xslt, gzip, servlets, transformer-model

I have the following code below in my Servlet, but when IE hits the page, it returns a blank html page.  If I use the response.getOutputStream() directly in the StreamResult constructor, the page loads fine.  What am I missing?

**response** is an instance of HttpServletResponse and **xsl** is an instance of Transformer from XSLTC TransformerFactory

```
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
Result outputResult = new StreamResult(gzipOut);

xsl.transform(xmlSource, outputResult);
```

Comment: do things work if you're using Firefox 3.x ? If NOT, most probably your code could use a fix as jsight suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you aren't closing the gzipOut stream and therefore it isn't sending the "footer" information.

Comment: Would closing the underlying response like: resp.getOutputStream().close(); 
work?

Comment: I honestly don't know. However, another technique may be to call gzipOut.finish() as it is able to print the final CRCs without closing the underlying stream. I'm not sure if/how GzipOutputStream would detect you calling close on the underlying stream, so I suspect that would actually make it worse.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out there is a .finish() on this stream that is required.  It is similar to flush, but since it is a different call, the Transformer does not know to use it.